# Google cloud jobs submit training gets stuck

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Hello while I had set up google cloud machine learning to train a neural network , suddenly I am unable to submit jobs to google cloud.

There is no error but the command hangs there without doing anything , Also my instance is running .Here is the command:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training job9123 --runtime-version 1.0 --job-dir gs://dataset1_giorgaros2 --package-path trainmodule  --module-name trainmodule.nncloud --region europe-west1 --config cloudml-gpu.yaml -- --train-file gs://dataset1_giorgaros2/nnn.p
```

Thank You !

Comment: Are you able to use gcloud to access other services?

Answer (score 1):

ML engine job logs could help to obtain more details about the failed job execution, in most of the cases the log file contains the cause for the failure.

[Finding the job logs on ML engine](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/troubleshooting#finding_the_logs)

If you are trying the same command each time over the training job execution, you might be obtaining an error regarding to the job name, this due to the name must be unique for each job on ML engine as it is described over the naming convention rules on ML engine jobs.

[ML Engine name convention](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/managing-models-jobs#creating_names_for_models_versions_and_jobs)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking network connectivity to google compute engine.

Check logs from the run - https://console.cloud.google.com/

And of course, read the docs: 
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/jobs/submit/training